# MySQL 5.6 -- How do I tell if I need to increase innodb io thread setting?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, connections

I am trying to tune my mysql server for the high end system. We are using 16--32 core hosts with memory > 100GB.

I have looked into a bunch of existing setting, but not sure if I need to tune up the innodb_read/write_io_threads. It is currently only set to 4 each.

```
| InnoDB |      | 
=====================================
2019-12-17 07:54:43 7f711dd6d700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 9 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 2400188 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 265 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 894
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 806244840
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 1019059878
Mutex spin waits 10940244001, rounds 62338475851, OS waits 590825553
RW-shared spins 566475375, rounds 5765275559, OS waits 128474028
RW-excl spins 19695565, rounds 1326338619, OS waits 15787881
Spin rounds per wait: -32.06 mutex, 10.18 RW-shared, 67.34 RW-excl
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
29500680050 OS file reads, 1193269217 OS file writes, 193602148 OS fsyncs
117.54 reads/s, 19527 avg bytes/read, 342.96 writes/s, 37.77 fsyncs/s
```

```
mysql> show status like 'max_used_connections';
+----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name        | Value |
+----------------------+-------+
| Max_used_connections | 174   |
+----------------------+-------+
```

It looks like the innodb io threads are sitting idle, but it is a bit counter intuitive there are a high number of threads connected and waiting to be executed.

Am I just reading the metrics wrong? Should I be bumping up the io thread settings?

Edit:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                                 | Value                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Aborted_clients                               | 106863                                           |
| Aborted_connects                              | 70                                               |
| Binlog_cache_disk_use                         | 0                                                |
| Binlog_cache_use                              | 0                                                |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use                    | 0                                                |
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use                         | 0                                                |
| Bytes_received                                | 1625547525701                                    |
| Bytes_sent                                    | 2286003139405                                    |
| Com_admin_commands                            | 8499339                                          |
| Com_change_db                                 | 1                                                |
| Com_commit                                    | 590982562                                        |
| Com_delete                                    | 107601707                                        |
| Com_help                                      | 0                                                |
| Com_insert                                    | 92217681                                         |
| Com_rollback                                  | 471568007                                        |
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint                     | 0                                                |
| Com_savepoint                                 | 0                                                |
| Com_select                                    | 2839611448                                       |
| Com_set_option                                | 1393872258                                       |
| Com_signal                                    | 0                                                |
| Com_show_databases                            | 17                                               |
| Com_show_engine_logs                          | 0                                                |
| Com_show_engine_mutex                         | 0                                                |
| Com_show_engine_status                        | 4                                                |
| Com_show_events                               | 0                                                |
| Com_show_errors                               | 0                                                |
| Com_show_fields                               | 369                                              |
| Com_show_function_code                        | 0                                                |
| Com_show_function_status                      | 0                                                |
| Com_show_grants                               | 0                                                |
| Com_show_keys                                 | 111                                              |
| Com_show_status                               | 23                                               |
| Com_show_storage_engines                      | 0                                                |
| Com_show_table_status                         | 0                                                |
| Com_show_tables                               | 21                                               |
| Com_show_triggers                             | 0                                                |
| Com_show_variables                            | 342355                                           |
| Com_update                                    | 841346886                                        |
| Compression                                   | OFF                                              |
| Connection_errors_accept                      | 0                                                |
| Connection_errors_internal                    | 0                                                |
| Connection_errors_max_connections             | 0                                                |
| Connection_errors_peer_address                | 0                                                |
| Connection_errors_select                      | 0                                                |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap                     | 0                                                |
| Connections                                   | 342450                                           |
| Created_tmp_disk_tables                       | 2334                                             |
| Created_tmp_files                             | 8                                                |
| Created_tmp_tables                            | 356072                                           |
| Delayed_errors                                | 0                                                |
| Delayed_insert_threads                        | 0                                                |
| Delayed_writes                                | 0                                                |
| Flush_commands                                | 1                                                |
| Handler_commit                                | 4470737313                                       |
| Handler_delete                                | 82094865                                         |
| Handler_discover                              | 0                                                |
| Handler_external_lock                         | 7759509648                                       |
| Handler_mrr_init                              | 0                                                |
| Handler_prepare                               | 0                                                |
| Handler_read_first                            | 1653297601                                       |
| Handler_read_key                              | 6492652384                                       |
| Handler_read_last                             | 0                                                |
| Handler_read_next                             | 5142902623                                       |
| Handler_read_prev                             | 0                                                |
| Handler_read_rnd                              | 3366143                                          |
| Handler_read_rnd_next                         | 3314986049                                       |
| Handler_rollback                              | 471332451                                        |
| Handler_savepoint                             | 0                                                |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback                    | 0                                                |
| Handler_update                                | 841346880                                        |
| Handler_write                                 | 183314643                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status                | not started                                      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status                | Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191121 19:04:32 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data                 | 509389                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data                 | 8345829376                                       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty                | 51724                                            |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty                | 847446016                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed              | 831165527                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free                 | 6243                                             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc                 | 8652                                             |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total                | 524284                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd             | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead                 | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted         | 18274                                            |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests              | 116508588463                                     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                      | 2534236537                                       |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free                  | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests             | 9553501411                                       |
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                            | 100038238                                        |
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs                    | 0                                                |
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                     | 0                                                |
| Innodb_data_pending_writes                    | 0                                                |
| Innodb_data_read                              | 46554305269760                                   |
| Innodb_data_reads                             | 2840557270                                       |
| Innodb_data_writes                            | 772657004                                        |
| Innodb_data_written                           | 28407884982784                                   |
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written                    | 831165527                                        |
| Innodb_dblwr_writes                           | 19505074                                         |
| Innodb_have_atomic_builtins                   | ON                                               |
| Innodb_log_waits                              | 0                                                |
| Innodb_log_write_requests                     | 2932109671                                       |
| Innodb_log_writes                             | 2358858                                          |
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs                          | 2534641                                          |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs                  | 0                                                |
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes                  | 0                                                |
| Innodb_os_log_written                         | 1172130567680                                    |
| Innodb_page_size                              | 16384                                            |
| Innodb_pages_created                          | 9089369                                          |
| Innodb_pages_read                             | 2841543370                                       |
| Innodb_pages_written                          | 831165527                                        |
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits                 | 0                                                |
| Innodb_row_lock_time                          | 0                                                |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg                      | 0                                                |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max                      | 0                                                |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits                         | 0                                                |
| Innodb_rows_deleted                           | 82094865                                         |
| Innodb_rows_inserted                          | 175266694                                        |
| Innodb_rows_read                              | 10220852902                                      |
| Innodb_rows_updated                           | 841346880                                        |
| Innodb_num_open_files                         | 24                                               |
| Innodb_truncated_status_writes                | 0                                                |
| Innodb_available_undo_logs                    | 128                                              |
| Key_blocks_not_flushed                        | 0                                                |
| Key_blocks_unused                             | 319666                                           |
| Key_blocks_used                               | 0                                                |
| Key_read_requests                             | 0                                                |
| Key_reads                                     | 0                                                |
| Key_write_requests                            | 0                                                |
| Key_writes                                    | 0                                                |
| Last_query_cost                               | 0.000000                                         |
| Last_query_partial_plans                      | 0                                                |
| Max_used_connections                          | 42                                               |
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows                      | 0                                                |
| Open_files                                    | 17                                               |
| Open_streams                                  | 0                                                |
| Open_table_definitions                        | 86                                               |
| Open_tables                                   | 246                                              |
| Opened_files                                  | 9475                                             |
| Opened_table_definitions                      | 86                                               |
| Opened_tables                                 | 253                                              |
| Performance_schema_accounts_lost              | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost          | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost        | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_digest_lost                | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_file_classes_lost          | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_file_handles_lost          | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_file_instances_lost        | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_hosts_lost                 | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_locker_lost                | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost         | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost       | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost        | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost      | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost        | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost      | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost         | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost     | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_table_handles_lost         | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_table_instances_lost       | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost        | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost      | 0                                                |
| Performance_schema_users_lost                 | 0                                                |
| Prepared_stmt_count                           | 0                                                |
| Qcache_free_blocks                            | 1                                                |
| Qcache_free_memory                            | 33536848                                         |
| Qcache_hits                                   | 0                                                |
| Qcache_inserts                                | 0                                                |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes                          | 0                                                |
| Qcache_not_cached                             | 2832134371                                       |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache                       | 0                                                |
| Qcache_total_blocks                           | 1                                                |
| Queries                                       | 6346278252                                       |
| Questions                                     | 6337778912                                       |
| Rsa_public_key                                |                                                  |
| Select_full_join                              | 111                                              |
| Select_full_range_join                        | 0                                                |
| Select_range                                  | 111074254                                        |
| Select_range_check                            | 0                                                |
| Select_scan                                   | 1062657891                                       |
| Slave_heartbeat_period                        | 0.000                                            |
| Slave_last_heartbeat                          |                                                  |
| Slave_open_temp_tables                        | 0                                                |
| Slave_received_heartbeats                     | 0                                                |
| Slave_retried_transactions                    | 0                                                |
| Slave_running                                 | OFF                                              |
| Slow_launch_threads                           | 0                                                |
| Slow_queries                                  | 14115                                            |
| Sort_merge_passes                             | 48                                               |
| Sort_range                                    | 5128                                             |
| Sort_rows                                     | 1833044                                          |
| Sort_scan                                     | 1                                                |
| Table_locks_immediate                         | 3878704926                                       |
| Table_locks_waited                            | 0                                                |
| Table_open_cache_hits                         | 3879758717                                       |
| Table_open_cache_misses                       | 253                                              |
| Table_open_cache_overflows                    | 0                                                |
| Tc_log_max_pages_used                         | 0                                                |
| Tc_log_page_size                              | 0                                                |
| Tc_log_page_waits                             | 0                                                |
| Threads_cached                                | 0                                                |
| Threads_connected                             | 41                                               |
| Threads_created                               | 167939                                           |
| Threads_running                               | 2                                                |
| Uptime                                        | 2246778                                          |
| Uptime_since_flush_status                     | 2246778                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: include `show global status like 'innodb_%'`.

Comment: Added the status. @danblack

Comment: Most of the values you presented are counters; they are useless without dividing by `Uptime`.  For more analysis, please provide all of `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` and `SHOW VARIABLES`.  There are dozens of settings that _may_ need tuning.

Comment: A high `Max_used_connections` _may_ mean that you have poor indexes.  Turn on the slowlog.

Comment: I put in most of the results from `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`, not being able add more since it is breaching the text size limit. Really appreciated for your help! @RickJames

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Paragraph 3 of ["Configuring the Number of Background InnoDB I/O Threads"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-performance-multiple_io_threads.html):

> If you have a high end I/O subsystem and you see more than 64 × innodb_read_io_threads pending read requests in SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS output, you might improve performance by increasing the value of innodb_read_io_threads.

Given the above `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`, you have

```
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
```

Everything has 0 for each I/O threads, so no threads were pending at that moment. If you ever start seeing 2 or 3 digit numbers instead of 0, then you will pending reads and writes in InnoDB.

This can also be seen in your global status

```
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                     | 0
| Innodb_data_pending_writes                    | 0
```

As shown, you have experienced no pending reads or writes in the InnoDB Storage Engine since mysqld last started.

You can periodically monitor `Innodb_data_pending_reads` or `Innodb_data_pending_writes`

You could also poll `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and look for nonzeros in `Pending normal aio`.

Personally, I raise both [innodb_read_io_threads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) and [innodb_write_io_threads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) it to 8 to match the default values for Percona Server and call it a day.

Comment: Is this documentation from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_data_pending_reads 
INCORRECT with the 'The current number of pending reads.'?  Want to be sure what the SHOW GLOBAL STATUS data represents, i.e. NOW or since startup of instance. Thanks

Comment: Seems to be from a current value looking at [variable code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/storage/innobase/srv/srv0srv.cc#L1339) and [incremented location](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/storage/innobase/os/os0file.cc#L2395) and shortly after a pread, [decremented](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/storage/innobase/os/os0file.cc#L2409) (and [where its called from](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.6/storage/innobase/os/os0file.cc#L2666)). Its it the number that is actively pending on a read. 6 hence is your io read threads + 2 more.

Comment: I am actually planning to increase the io read/write threads to half total number of cores, which means for our strongest host, that is 24 threads for each, is there any bad side effects for setting the io threads number too high? We have other JVM services running on the host as well, I am not sure if that would impact other services ability to process requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have good use of innodb buffer pool.

`Innodb_data_pending_reads` is an outlier a bit, monitor its level. If its frequently non-zero, a small increase in `innodb_read_io_threads` to 8 or so should reduce contention.

This is still only as good as your storage hardware.

Comment: 131219 Threads_created _per hour_ is very high.  But 131219/year is insignificant.

Comment: I am not sure how to read the "thread_created" count, is that threads created ever since the mysql started running? @RickJames

Comment: Looking at the buffer pool hit rate, I got 96% hit rate using the formular `（Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests - Innodb_buffer_pool_reads） / Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests * 100%`. Is 96% hit rate considered bad already? @danblack

Comment: Quite right on all counts. I misread the read rate. Uptime certainly puts Threads_created into perspective. mea culpa

Comment: @JialunLiu - @96% is somewhat low.  How much RAM?  How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Need the `VARIABLES`, too.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: @RickJames -- The host we are running has 100GB and 32 cores, we only allocated 8GB to buffer_pool and 8 buffer_pool_instance before, I am bumping it up to about 40GB buffer_pool and 10 buffer_pool_instance. Since our database is pretty large, around 1.1TB.

Comment: @JialunLiu - That is likely to push the "hit rate" closer to 100%.  And speed up things in general.